# Should I cull elements before rendering to HTML5 canvas or let the canvas cull

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Should I cull elements before calling the canvas draw methods or let the canvas handle culling. Should I implement logic like:

```
if(circle.x+circle.radius>=0 || circle.x-circle.radius<canvas.width || circle.y+circle.radius>=0 || circle.y-circle.radius<canvas.height)
  context.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,2.Math.PI,false);
```

or

should I just call context.arc and let the canvas figure out what to draw or not?

I hope this makes sense? I will be writing some code to test this but any input would be appreciated.... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Canvas" (ie. browser internals) will check these values regardless in any case and perform clipping if values are outside boundaries (or just use the system's low-level clipping ability for bitmaps).

For that reason there is no point doing boundary checks in JS first, but also because the internal checks are more efficient than doing it in JS.

Canvas drawing is designed to be pretty safe and does not only perform clipping, but also clamps color values and so forth.